# Dealing with Errors on Selenium Headless Handling

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, error-handling

I have created a web scraper that reads a dynamic table on a webpage that is live updating. I'm not sure the best way to do this... so I decided to just read the table every 30 seconds and take the results from there. Anyway, the website I am using to webscrape is pretty buggy and an error message pops up pretty often on the webpage:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RexEI.png)

This error message causes my code to stop due to it reporting an error. Ideally, I would like to just move on and reload the webpage 30 seconds later and just miss out on this scrape. Currently, my code returns an error that it can't find the table I am looking for and then the code stops.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\New Jaden\Documents\GitHub\dfk\test.py", line 108, in <module>
    make_data()
  File "C:\Users\New Jaden\Documents\GitHub\dfk\test.py", line 91, in make_data
    print(type(wd.page_source))
  File "C:\Users\New Jaden\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 926, in page_source
    return self.execute(Command.GET_PAGE_SOURCE)['value']
  File "C:\Users\New Jaden\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\New Jaden\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 246, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: DataTables warning: table id=saleAuctionTable - Requested unknown parameter '13' for row 0, column 13. For more information about this error, please see 
http://datatables.net/tn/4
Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : DataTables warning: table id=saleAuctionTable - Requested unknown parameter '13' for row 0, column 13. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4}
```

My code snippet would be as follows:

```
def make_data():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

    url = 'https://dfktavern.com/saleAuction-alert'

    wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)
    wd.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)

    html = wd.page_source

    df = pd.read_html(html)
```

The error happens on the line:

```
html = wd.page_source
```

I basically am just looking for, instead of my code breaking, for my code to just ignore the rest and wait for the next call to be made to do this again.

Comment: read about try: except and error handling?!

Comment: I can't find it in these docs.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html

Comment: Those are called alerts what you can do is try except look for it and then handle if it exists.